# How to Store Datetime Values in Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

Given the following functions to create and then retrieve an item...

```
type Auth struct {
    UserID string `dynamodbav:"UserId"`
    ExpiresOn time.Time `dynamodbav:"ExpiresOn,unixtime"`
}

func (r *AuthRepository) Create(auth *Auth) (*Auth, error) {
    deviceCode, err := c.NewDeviceCode()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    item, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(auth)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        Item:      item,
        TableName: aws.String("MyTable"),
    }
    _, err = r.svc.PutItem(r.ctx, input)
    return auth, nil
}

func (r *AuthRepository) Get(userID string) (*Auth, error) {
    input := &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String("MyTable"),
        Key: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
            "UserId": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{*aws.String(userID)},
        },
    }

    result, err := r.svc.GetItem(r.ctx, input)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var auth *Auth = nil
    if len(result.Item) > 0 {
        auth = &Auth{}
        if err := attributevalue.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &auth); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    return auth, nil
}
```

... I create a new item with that should expire in 30 minutes like this:

```
repo.Create(&auth.Auth{
        UserID:   "XYZ",
        ExpiresOn: time.Now().Add(time.Duration(1800) * time.Second), // expires in 30 mins
    })
```

Then, I retrieve the item created above and I check whether it has expired:

```
authEntry, err := repo.GetByUserCode("XYZ")

if authEntry.ExpiresOn.Before(time.Now()) {
    // I always get here as Before evaluates to true
}
```

As I noted in the code snippet above, if I create an entry with an expiry time of now + 30 minutes, and then I immediately retrieve that record to check if `ExpiresOn` is before now, I always get `true`...

What's the correct way to store datetime in DynamoDB?

Comment: From the [supported data types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html), are you creating a ISO 8601 string?

Comment: have you done any debugging? what is the value of authEntry.ExpiresOn when you call getByUserCode?